# What is the return type for a generic list returning an anonymous 2-string type?

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

I have this function:

```
public static List<string> JoinDataTablesMultipleColumns(DataTable dt1, DataTable dt2, string col1, string col2, string col3) {
 var multiJoin = from table1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
 join table2 in dt2.AsEnumerable()
 on new {
   Col1 = table1.Field < string > (col1),
   Col2 = table1.Field < string > (col2),
   Col3 = table1.Field < string > (col3),
 }
 equals new {
   Col1 = table2.Field < string > (col1),
   Col2 = table2.Field < string > (col2),
   Col3 = table2.Field < string > (col3),
 }
 select new {
   SeriesID = table1.Field < string > ("SeriesID"),
   CatID = table2.Field < string > ("CatID")
 };

 //if ( multiJoin != null )
 //   return multiJoin.ToList();
 //else
 return null;
}
```

It works perfectly except that I have the wrong return type. The only way I can compile and run it is by returning null. When I stop the debugger before returning and examine `multiJoin.ToList()` in the `watch window`, it's exactly what I want:

[image]

But the return type is wrong. I keep trying `List<string, string>`, but that won't compile. Probably a simple thing but I am stuck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of attempting returning an anonymous type (you can't declare an anonymous return type for your method), create a named type to hold your data:

```
public class Item
{
    public string SeriesID { get; set;}
    //...
}
```

and use it instead of the anonymous type that you are currently selecting at the end of your query.

```
...select new Item {
   SeriesID = table1.Field < string > ("SeriesID"),
   CatID = table2.Field < string > ("CatID")
 };
```

Comment: In the end, this approach may be a little more old-school than Eric's, but it doesn't cause me to lose named properties as the `tuple` does.

Comment: This would be so much cleaner if we had [Record Types](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/features/records.md).  They're specifically designed to solve this sort of problem.  Alas, it keeps getting pushed back.  There are a surprising number of low-level implementation details that have made it difficult to come up with a spec for this.

Answer (score 12):

As you note, you're getting a list of anonymous type. **Anonymous types are not designed to cross out of the methods that create them**.  There are ways to make that work, but they are confusing, difficult and arcane.

Do not attempt to do this with anonymous types. In C# 7, you can use a tuple type and return `List<(string, string)>`, and then do

```
select (table1.Field<string>("SeriesID"), table2.Field<string>("CatID"))
```

In other versions of C#, **make a nominal pair type** and create an instance of it in your select clause.

Comment: When you say `make a nominal pair type`, is that the same as what `spender` is suggesting?

Comment: I must be in c# 7 because the compiler doesn't complain about `List<(string, string)>`, but then it complains about what I'm returning: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: string SeriesID, string CatID>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<(string, string)>'`

Comment: @HerrimanCoder: Hah, I was typing up the solution to that problem as you were typing up the comment.

Comment: Going the tuple route, I'd probably go for a `List<(string SeriesID,string CatID)>` making the data returned in the tuple easy to work with at the other end of the method call.

Comment: @HerrimanCoder: Also, there are techniques you can use in C# 7 to associate names with your tuple.

Comment: @spender: Apparently this is the day of me typing things at the same time as other people.

Comment: @HerrimanCoder: In general, if you're using C# 7 then today would be a great day to start using tuples for the things you would normally have used anonymous types for, particularly if the tuples are small.

Comment: @HerrimanCoder: Fix your select clause so that it creates a tuple instead of an anonymous type.

Comment: @EricLippert - done, and it works. But I lose `SeriesID` and `CatID` in the return value, replaced by `Item1` and `Item2`. Still works fine, but seems like not having butter on my bread now. Is there a way to be able to reference those by name? As in `retVal[0].SeriesID`, etc?

Comment: I have re-read the comments, what am I missing? I have fixed my select: `select (table1.Field<string>("SeriesID"), table2.Field<string>("CatID"));`

Comment: @HerrimanCoder: I don't know what typo you have. Works on my machine:    `static List<(string Foo, string Bar)> M() {
        var s = Enumerable.Range(0, 1);
        var q = from x in s select ("hello ", "world");
        return q.ToList();
    }
    static void Main() {
        var m = M();
        Console.WriteLine(m[0].Foo + m[0].Bar);
    }`

Comment: @EricLippert: thanks for your patience. If you could give the full source in your answer, it would help. As I said, it works, but I still get generic Item1, Item2 in the calling code. In googling on tuple usage, this is what others get also.